# opencart : create_sid error . how can i sold?

Tags: php, session, opencart2.x

i make a website use opencart and i got an error last days about create_sid.
website work perfectly localhost but not in ftp.

i work hard session class and i saw it native session class extends SessionHandler and native class has a function like that

session start like this :

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

native class :

```
<?php
namespace Session;
class Native extends \SessionHandler {
public function create_sid() {
     return parent::create_sid();
}
```

and when this line was exexuted throw and error this

> sessionHandler::create_sid(): Cannot call default session handler in Unknown on line 0

session class :

```
 public function __construct($adaptor = 'native') {
    $class = 'Session\\' . $adaptor;

    if (class_exists($class)) {
        $this->adaptor = new $class($this);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Error: Could not load session adaptor ' . $adaptor . ' session!');
    }       

    if ($this->adaptor) {
        session_set_save_handler($this->adaptor);
    }

    if ($this->adaptor && !session_id()) {
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'Off');
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
        ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');

        if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,52}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            exit('Error: Invalid session ID!');
        }

        session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
        session_start();
    }           
}

public function start($key = 'default', $value = '') {
    if ($value) {
        $this->session_id = $value;
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$key])) {
        $this->session_id = $_COOKIE[$key];
    } else {
        //error was created this line
        $this->session_id = $this->createId();
    }   

    if (!isset($_SESSION[$this->session_id])) {
        $_SESSION[$this->session_id] = array();
    }

    $this->data = &$_SESSION[$this->session_id];

    if ($key != 'PHPSESSID') {
        setcookie($key, $this->session_id, ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'), ini_get('session.cookie_path'), ini_get('session.cookie_domain'), ini_get('session.cookie_secure'), ini_get('session.cookie_httponly'));
    }

    return $this->session_id;
}

 public function createId() {
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5.4', '>') == true) {
        return $this->adaptor->create_sid();
    } elseif (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        return substr(bin2hex(random_bytes(26)), 0, 26);
    } elseif (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        return substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(26)), 0, 26);
    } else {
        return substr(bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(26, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), 0, 26);
    }
}
```

if i remove $session->start(); line site works.

how can i sold it ?

Answer (score 1):

the source code for PHP is similar to:

```
abstract class SessionHandlerInterface {
    public string create_sid ( void );
}

Session_Implementation_Instance implements SessionHandlerInterface {
    //compiled code runs this
    public function create_sid () {
       //actual function code
    }
}
```

When you extend/implement the SessionHandlerInterface, you get a blank slate with no developed code or parent::functions to refer back to. You do not get to extend the functional/concrete class that runs in the default deployment.

This unfortunately requires you to know what you are doing when you are coding it... As well as not providing much details with the class definition.

Details about it are provided at its siblings (non-class) definition with much more discussion as its existed longer, which you can also look to for `open`, `read`, `write`, `close` and other needed functions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php